# deserialize two different date formats with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Im consuming a clients JSON API using googles GSON lib to handle serialisation/deserialization.
This is proving to be problematic as within the API's json entities there are a number of date formats scattered about the API.

Some examples of this are as follows...

"2014-02-09"

"15/10/1976"

"2014-02-09T07:32:41+00:00"

I have no control over the API as it developerd by the client and is already being consumed by other parties.
It seems that I can setup GSON to work with a single date format but I cant get it parse the dates on a per field basis.

I would have expected GOSN to provide an annotation for this but I cant seem to find one.
Any ideas on ho to set this up anyone?

Comment: Note that JSON does not define a standard date format.  Dates can be in any character format or as seconds or milliseconds since some epoch date -- it's entirely up to the sender.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have multiple `Date` fields in your POJO, and the incomming JSON has those dates in different formats, you'd need to write a custom deserializer for `Date` that can handle those formats.

```
class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date>
{
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException
    {
        String myDate = je.getAsString();
        // inspect string using regexes
        // convert string to Date        
        // return Date object
    }

}
```

You can the register this as a type adapter when creating your Gson instance:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer())
                .create();
```

You can, of course, also just write a custom deserializer for your POJO and populate everything yourself from the parse tree.

Another option would be to simply set them as a `String` in your POJO, then make the getters for each field convert them to `Date`.

Outside of that, if you're not completely attached to using Gson, the Jackson JSON parser (by default) uses your POJO's setters during deserializtion which would give you the explicit control over setting each field.

Comment: Not realy ideal due to the limitations of GSON. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @carrot_programmer_3 The other option is, of course, writing custom deserializers for your classes that have the multiple date formats. While that could be somewhat tedious to write it would sove the problem.